# Back button doesn't detect created() on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, back

so i have some code in created

```
created() {
    if(!this.$session.exists() && !this.exists) {
      if(this.$router.currentRoute.path != '/login'){
        this.loginAlert = true
        this.$router.push('/login') 
      }
    }else{
      this.login = this.$session.get('uname')
      this.exists = true
    }
  },
```

this is working when i refresh my page

my vue is localhost:8081

so when i open localhost:8081 it will alert not login yet and redirect to localhost:8081/login. But after redirect and i press back button on the browser, the localhost:8081 link is open and the alert doesn't show up so it's like bypass

how can i fix this?

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve, it looks like you didn't read properly when `created` is actually running in the vue life cycle (https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). I guess you can solve your issue moving this logic in the router and check session validity there, but its hard to tell since we don't know what you wanna achieve.

Comment: so if sessions is not set then user can't go to localhost:8081/. They must login first in localhost:8081/login.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is created only once, so it will not call again after redirect. You can try add `:key` on your `<router-view>`

`<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">`

Comment: Try to use router hook beforeEach or beforeEnter
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards